# HP Spectre 360 not charging, LED lights do not glow and computer does not start

Tags: windows-10, charging

While I was playing a game on my notebook which was plugged in the charger, the battery got drained and it stopped charging. When I pressed the power button, it blinked 3 times but the notebook wouldn't start.

We disconnected and reconnected the battery and did a reset by holding the power button for 15 seconds. The power led was red and I left it in the charger overnight. On the next morning, the power led was white and blinking. I started the notebook and I got a CMOS error 5403 or 5304 (can't remember exactly), but Windows started and I could log in. The battery was at 4%. I turned the notebook off and the power led stopped again.

We ordered a new battery assuming that the battery is the problem since the notebook is pretty old (4-5 years). We put in the new battery but the power led is still off and the notebook won't start. If I plug it in the charger then there is a short sound.

We tried most if not all of the recommendations on the HP Support site.
Any ideas what the problem could be and how to fix it?

Comment: The charger has failed.

Comment: I tried with 3 different chargers but it's not working with either.

Comment: Chargers are very specific to each laptop, so you had access to 2 other Spectre 360 chargers?

Comment: I tried with two other brands that worked in the last 5 years without any problems and one original from HP.